# Schema crawler reading data from table

Tags: schemacrawler

I understood we can read data from a table using command in Schema crawler.

How to do that programatically in java. I could see example to read schema , table etc. But how to get data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SchemaCrawler allows you to obtain database metadata, including result set metadata. Standard JDBC provides you a way to get data by using `java.sql.ResultSet`, and you can use SchemaCrawler for obtainting result set metadata using `schemacrawler.utility.SchemaCrawlerUtility.getResultColumns(ResultSet)`.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/)